# Matplotlib change gap between bars and add black outline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted some graph by:

```
plt.bar(TIME, MC_SIM, width=2000)
```

I have:
[image]

How can I plot it with another gap between bars and black outline? Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the points on the x axis are equally spaced, you can set the width of the bars equal to the difference between x coordinates,

```
plt.bar(x, y, width=x[1]-x[0])
```

If the x coordinates are unequally spaced, you need to provide a list of widths, which correspond to the distance between successive bars.

In order to still leave some space between the bars, you can then adapt the width. E.g. if you want to have 20% spacing between bars,

```
plt.bar(x, y, width=(x[1]-x[0])*0.8)
```

To show the outline, use `ec="black"` as further argument.

Comment: Very good! But a little improvement: What is need to make plot look like this? https://unmaintainable.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/bar-1.png

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by "like this"? I thought you did not want to have spaces between bars?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will change a question a little bit. Could you help with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
# Use this code to get the axes
axs = plt.gca()

# Here you set where de y axis begins and ends
# In this case, the y axis end will be 20% bigger than the biggest value in your y list of values (MC_SIM)
axs.set_ybound(lower=0, upper=max(MC_SIM)*1.2)
```